# Deployed shiny app does not display PDF, but instead triggers automatic download of PDF

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display a PDF in my shiny app using the following code snippets:

UI:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage(...tabPanel(title = "pdffile",
       tabPanel(title = "pdf Page",
                uiOutput("pdffile"))),...)
```

Server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {...output$pdffile <- renderUI({
tags$iframe(style = "height:750px; width:100%; scrolling = yes", src = "pdffile.pdf")})})
```

When I run the app locally, everything works great. The app opens a PDF window in which one can scroll through the PDF, download it or print it - exactly what I wanted.

However, opening the app online, an automatic download of the PDF is triggered (which I do **NOT** want) and the there is only an empty rectangle on the webpage, where the PDF window with all its functionalities is supposed to be.

I should mention that this is my first Shiny app, so please keep that in mind when answering.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that it must have something do do with my browser settings because everything works as expected on my phone and on another computer.

Comment: You can make this an edit to your original question rather than making it an "answer" because this hasn't necessarily cleared up why this behavior occurred in the first place